# java swing clipping problem

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I have a swing component which draws a fixed large (but fixed) vector image and overlays parts of the image with text which should display relative to the view port (not the absolute position) -- think frozen row labels in excel (illustrated below):

```
Header
 -- [some stuff] ----- [ some stuff] ----
Header2
 ----- [some stuff] ----- [ some stuff] ----
```

This works fine except when scrolling left to right.  I try to set the clip bounds to the visible region in the paintComponent() method so that the entire viewport is always drawn -- however this does not appear to work:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
  Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
  Shape oldClip = g.getClip();

  Rectangle clipBounds = getVisibleRect();
  g.setClip(clipBounds);

  drawMyImage();
  drawMyHeaders();

  g.setClip(oldClip);
}
```

However, this does not seem to work, I see the visible region is the right shape, but setting the clip has no effect.  What can I do?

```
clip: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1762,y=0,width=57,height=182]    // clipped while scrolling
 vis: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1762,y=0,width=582,height=182]   // what I want to paint
```

Comment: Don't use `setClip` in `paintComponent`! The clipping region is used by Swing.

Comment: Obviously I'm asking for the better approach -- but there should be no harm is setting it to the visible region, drawing, then restoring it.  Swing seems to ensure that the clip is hard set to the dirty region while scrolling, perhaps providing a graphics sub-context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the graphics object into your headers, so they must be painting through something else which probably wont have your clipping shape set.

As commented, don't use setClip in paintComponent! The clipping region is used by Swing.

It seems what you want to do is have an overlay component layered above the scrolling component.

Comment: Everything paints as part of a single timeline component.  The calculation of the positions of the headers come out during the painting of the timeline -- Thus I don't really want to overlay a second swing component over top.

Comment: How would an overlay component set its position so it draws properly in a scroll pane?

Comment: @Justin Assuming no layout manager, just setting its position within the parent component when the scrolling area moves. YOu could split horizontal and vertical scrolling, but that is likely to have side-effects.

Comment: So from within a custom scrollbar adjustmentListener?  I did try this, but the listener applies AFTER the scroll action (I invalidated the entire drawing area each scroll).  You see the scroll draw (with damage), then redraw properly.  A custom layout manager seems like it is reaquired -- ugh!